# Is it possible to put a javascript in the PostBackUrl of the LinkButton

Tags: javascript, webforms, postback, linkbutton

I want to know if its possible for a javascript to run in the linkbutton's postbackurl. Or is there any way to trigger a javascript in linkbutton.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="editlink" onclick="LinkButton1_Click" PostBackUrl="javascript:document.getElementById('sched').style.display = 'block';" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnClientClick`. For example:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="MyFunction();" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

It will fire before the OnClick event.

Your Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
  function MyFunction() {
   document.getElementById('sched').style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>
```

Add an `UpdatePanel` for an AsyncPostBack

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="MyFunction();" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
      <ProgressTemplate>
          <div id="sched">
            // Your code
          </div>
      </ProgressTemplate>
  </asp:UpdateProgress>      
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: It displays what I want to display but suddenly, after postback, it disappears.

Comment: That is correct, the page is reloaded after postback. If you want it to persist you probably want to add an `UpdatePanel` with a `UpdateProgress` template so it is only a partial postback.

Comment: Did you put `<script>` tags around the function? I'll update the answer.

Comment: It is already inside the updatepanel. my problem is it is disappearing because of the postback.

Comment: It is really not working. i forgot to tell that my linkbutton is inside the gridview. and the error is it is looking for the control id..

Comment: You will need to use the `FindControl` method to get the control `ID`. Do a bit of a search for finding a control nested in a gridview and you should find your answer.